# TypeORM repository createQueryBuilder catches error but continues execution

Tags: node.js, typeorm

```
import { getCustomRepository } from "typeorm";
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from "express";
import { UserRepository } from "../repositories/user-repository";

export class UserController {

  private userRepository = getCustomRepository(UserRepository);
  all = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    // return this.userRepository.find();
    let users = await this.userRepository
      .createQueryBuilder('users')
      .addSelect('users.passworda')
      .getMany()
      .catch(err => {
        console.log("Reached1");
        return next(err);
      })

    console.log("Reached2");
  }

}
```

I was expecting Reached2 will never be called if there is an exception and only Reached1 gets called.
But both Reached1 and Reached2 gets called in sequence.
To simulate a DB error, i used passworda instead of password db field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the promise returned by `getMany()` get rejected (an exception was thrown) it get catched and `next()` is called:

```ts
.getMany()
.catch(err => {
    console.log("Reached1");
    return next(err);
});
```

The resulting promise returned by `catch` itself is resolved successfully because the exception was handled before with a resulting value of `undefined`. So `let users` will hold `undefined` and the code execution continues to `console.log("Reached2");`.

---

The following code will behave as you have expected:

```ts
  all = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {

    try {

      let users = await this.userRepository
        .createQueryBuilder('users')
        .addSelect('users.passworda')
        .getMany();

      console.log("Reached2");

    } catch (err) {
      console.log("Reached1");
      return next(err);
    }

  }
```